# ¿Cómo elimino los elementos que contengan la cadena indicada?

Tags: python

Crear una función que reciba una lista de palabras y una cadena y quite las palabras en las que aparezcan todas las letras de la cadena.

> Por ej: ["celular","servicio","datos","revista"] y "sri" devuelve
> ["celular","datos"]

Por ahora realicé esto, pero lo malo es que solo elimina la cadena de la palabra.

```
l = ["celular","servicio","datos","revista"]
p = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    for elem in l[i]:
        p.append(elem)
print(p)

s = input("Cadena:")
y = []
for eleme in s:
    if eleme not in y:
        y.append(eleme)
print(y)

ez = ""
for e in p:
    if e not in y:
        ez = ez + e
print(ez)
```

Comment: Deberías haber editado tu pregunta anterior en lugar de crear una nueva.

Comment: Error de principiante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la funcion `all()` para buscar si una cadena contiene todos los caracteres, por ejemplo:

```
chars = ["s", "o", "t","a","d"]
palabra = "datos"
contiene_caracteres = all([char in palabra for char in chars])
print(contiene_caracteres)
```

salida:

```
True
```

---

Si implementas lo anterior en tu código:

```
l = ["celular","servicio","datos","revista"]
p = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    for elem in l[i]:
        p.append(elem)
print(p)

s = input("Cadena:")
y = []
for eleme in s:
    if eleme not in y:
        y.append(eleme)

for item in l.copy():
    contiene_caracteres = all([char in item for char in y])
    if (contiene_caracteres):
        l.remove(item)

print("lista final",l)
```

Si introduces la cadena "sotad", obtendrías como salida:

```
lista final ['celular', 'servicio', 'revista']
```

ya que eliminaría la palabra "datos" que contiene los caracteres de la cadena "sotad".

Answer (score 0):

Amigo te propongo una solucion basado en tu propuesta

```
lista = ["celular","servicio","dato","revista"]
print(lista)
```

No dividas en caracteres todas las palabras de la lista

```
s = input("Cadena:")
res = ""
```

Con la palabra que deseas usar para descartar palabra crea un concatenado de texto donde agregaras True or False dependiendo si encuentra o no la letra dentro la palabra del listado

Basicamente si todas las comparaciones son True la palabra no se agrega a la oracion final caso contrario si

Dentro de este save guardara True siempre que encuentra una letra del texto a comparar, pero si guarda un False indica que no concuerdan todas las letras y puede ser guardado

```
for palabra in lista:
    save = ""    
    for letter in s:
        save = save + str(letter in palabra)
    if "False" in save:
        res = res +" "+ item
print(res)
```

perdon si no me puedo explicarme mejor.
Buen dia

Answer (score 0):

Una opción compacta e interesante es utilizar un filtrado:

```
filtro=filter(lambda x:all([char in x for char in set(s)]),l)
```

Esto lo que hace obtener las palabra que contiene el conjunto de caracteres de tu entrada 's' del input, luego puedes borrarlas de la lista recorriendo el filtro.

*Nota:

set("iris") devuelve ['i','r','s']
El conjunto sin repetición de la cadena  o lista que le pases